# Difference between dup and dup_x2

Tags: java, stack, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, opcode

I'm currently playing with bit of Java bytecode. I have read about two opcodes: `dup` and `dup2`. If I understand it correctly, then the only difference between them is that first duplicates only one stack word, while second duplicates pair of stack words. This is good, but each of them has their own subopcodes (`dup_x1`, `dup2_x2`...).

When I look on function of for example `dup_x2` and `dup2_x1`, they seem to do same thing: duplicating top three values in order (so from values `val4, val3, val2, val1` there are `val4, val3, val2, val1, val3, val2, val1`). I'm confused, because there's no reason for defining two opcodes for same action.

What are these opcodes for then? Is there any official reference for their action? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any official reference for their action?

Of course there is!  It is the JVM specification - specifically [section 6.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5).

I won't copy it here.  Follow the link and read it all yourself.  But the basic idea is that the `dup_x1` and `dup_x2` variants are inserting the duplicate value/values lower down the stack.

> I'm confused, because there's no reason for defining two opcodes for same action.

Look carefully (in the spec).  They are not doing the same thing.

Comment: The documentation says "two or three values down", how does JVM decide if two or three?

Comment: The JVMS says that it depends on what is on the top of the stack.  If the top 3 elements are category 1 (32 bit) values, it is 3 values down.  If they are a category 1 and a category 2 (64 bit), it is 2 values down.